# Facebook Graph API - get event attending list

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a page that acts as the admin of various events. I am attempting to retrieve a list of people who have RSVPed as attending.

I used to be able to access this list with the following, where the access token was generated by an app I created:

```
FB.api(
  '/{event-id}/attending',
  'GET',
  {'access_token':{access-token}},
  function(response) {
    // Insert your code here
  }
);
```

This now results in a permission error.

I've used the [explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to try generating different types of access tokens, but all I can get from that edge now is an empty data object.

I've read that permissions errors will fail silently in this manner, but I can't figure out what permissions I need to retrieve this data. Even when I use an access token from the page (which is listed as an event admin), I come up with nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is no longer possible to get the attendees:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#events-4-4

> GET /events — You can no longer get the following edges:
>
> - attending
> - comments
> - declined
> - feed
> - interested
> - live_videos
> - maybe
> - noreply
> - photos
> - pictures
> - posts
> - videos